# How to correctly reference an object method within itself in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the correct way to reference an object function from within itself, so that I can call it several times using setTimeout in Javascript? In other words I want to be able to do this:

```
Foo.prototype.move = function() {
  if (this.count_a < 5) {
    this.count_a += 1;
    // setTimeout(this.move, 500);                    // doesn't work
    // setTimeout(function() { this.move(); }, 500);  // doesn't work
  }
}
```

I have tried a couple of things, none of which seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tga8r/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `this` property within the timeout will point to the object, that does execute the passed callback.

use `.bind(this)` to say, that the invoker have to use the this point to the passed object.

```
Foo.prototype.move = function() {
  if (this.count_a < 5) {
    this.count_a += 1;
    // setTimeout(this.move, 500);                    
    setTimeout(function() { this.move(); }.bind(this), 500);  
  }
}
```

or use a reference:

```
Foo.prototype.move = function() {
  var self = this;
  if (this.count_a < 5) {
    this.count_a += 1;
    // setTimeout(this.move, 500);                    
    setTimeout(function() { self.move(); }, 500);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this has a global scope when  the window timer function runs- it is out of your function and in the window.

label the **this**-

```
Foo.prototype.move= function(){
    var T= this;
    if(T.count_a<5){
        T.count_a += 1;
        setTimeout(function(){T.move();},500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function move (a) {
    setTimeout(
        function() { 
           if (a < 10) {
            a = a+ 1; 
            move(a);
           } 
        }, 500); }

move(0);
```